# How to handle Webview click event in Android Java

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm using `WebView` in my Android app. I want to run `Push Notification` when users click on a button. Can anyone help me to provide java code to handle the `onClick` button of `WebView`.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this in `Android` by using `JavascriptInterface`

Create class  in your `Activity`, Name it as `JavaScriptInterface` class. create method
`onButtonClick()` inside the class

```
public class JavaScriptInterface {
        Context mContext;

        /**
         * Instantiate the interface and set the context
         */
        JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }


        @JavascriptInterface
        public void onButtonClick() {
           // Handle your code

        }

    }
```

Add this class reference to `WebView` like below.

```
 webview.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");
```

And in your `WebPage` you have to call `onButtonClick()` method in `WebPage` `Button` click

Below is code

```
<html>
    <body>
    <a onClick="onButtonClick()"> Click me, i am JS Button </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

This will call your Activity `onButtonClick()` method.

**Hope this will help** for more clarification you check this [link](https://tausiq.wordpress.com/2012/12/03/android-java-and-javascript-interfacing-in-android-webview/)